# How does ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration) work in the app directory in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

In the `pages` directory we had ISR, which we can use to generate static pages at build time. I would like to do the same in the `app` directory. Is it possible? If not, can I use the `pages` directory alongside the `app` directory and do ISR in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read on the [migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#incremental-static-regeneration-getstaticprops-with-revalidate), in the `app` directory, data fetching with `fetch()` can use the `revalidate` option to make ISR:

```js
// app/page.js

export default async function Page() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts`, { next: { revalidate: 60 } })
  const posts = await res.json()
 
  return posts.map((post) => <div>{post.name}</div>)
}
```

And if you are not using `fetch()`, but something like Axios, or an ORM like Prisma, the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#background-revalidation) suggests using [route segment config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate), as an example like so:

```js
// app/page.js

export const revalidate = 60 // revalidate this page every 60 seconds

export default async function Page {
  return "..."
}
```

Also, data can be revalidated on-demand by path with [`revalidatePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) or by cache tag with [`revalidateTag`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag). For example using [Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers):

```js
// app/api/revalidate/route.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
 
export async function GET(request) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('path') || '/'
  revalidatePath(path)
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() })
}
```

Comment: Can we not revalidate using an api call. That means only when required?

Comment: You can do that with [On-Demand Revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#using-on-demand-revalidation).

Comment: Thank you so much it totally worked. On-Deman Revalidation should also work as per doc but I will be adding that in the next iteration of the product.